# Cannot see all files in Samba share

Tags: windows-7, permissions, samba

I have a user who is traveling overseas and is connecting to our samba fileserver on a `Windows 7` machine.  He is able to authenticate and open the share just file, he can traverse through his sub folders.  The issue is that in one of his subfolders there are many more folders and documents, but he can only see 1 of them.  Inside of that 1 folder that he can see, there should be many files but he can only see a few of them.

I checked the permissions and all the files are owned by him and he has the `rwx` permissions on everything so there is no issue on that front.  When I log in as him on my local computer, I can see all the files just fine.

He mentioned that the only files he can see seem to be "Recent" files that he has accessed.  He also said when he first began the travels he saw everything just fine, but about 3 weeks ago is when only the "Recent" things appeared.

I have had him restart the computer as well as manually disconnection and reconnect to the share but no luck.  Like i mentioned, I also logged in using his account and it was fine.

So there must be something specific on his computer like its in a cached mode or something so its only showing him things he recently looked at but not getting the fresh data from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a remote desktop session and being able to see for myself, turns out it was a network connection issue.  The drive was being loaded in offline mode, thus basically showing him a cache.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
But when I use ssh and type  ls -f   I can see there are some files with spaces at the begging or at the end of the file name. This causes samba to hide the file.

For example

'myfolder/ this is bad.doc'
'myfolder/bad .doc'
'myfolder /doc.txt'
' myfolder/doc.txt'